# How to receive various results from MySQL 'LIKE'?

Tags: php, mysql

So, i wrote this code, and it works. But, it only returns one result. So i have 2 'Eric Clapton' name in my database, each with different id's. But the query only returns one of those 2. Any ideas?

```
<?php

$now = htmlentities(rawurldecode($_GET['word'])); // in this case i passed in 'Eric Clapton'
$cat = htmlentities($_GET['cat']); // category, in this case lets say i passed in 'music'

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASS");
if (!$con)
  {
  echo "<pre>An error occured, please try again later. Sorry...</pre>"; 
  }
else{ mysql_select_db("DATABASE", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM $cat WHERE name LIKE '%$now%'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";

mysql_close($con);  
}
?>
```

Truth, now we're talking->

```
<?php

$now = '%'.htmlentities(rawurldecode($_GET['word'])).'%';
$cat = htmlentities($_GET['cat']); 

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=DATABASE;host=localhost';
$user = "USER";
$password = "PASS";

# connect to the database
try {
    $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    # the data we want to insert
    $data = array($now);

    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM $cat WHERE name LIKE ?");
    $STH->execute($data);
    $result = $STH->fetchAll();

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Uh-Oh, something wen't wrong. Please try again later.";
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

$DBH = null;

?>
```

Comment: You should really sanitize your input and/or move the PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: what do you think of 'mysql_real_escape_string' ? On both $cat and $word before doing the query.

Comment: Good, but I'd really prefer (and so should you!) if you moved to PDO. It's so much better, you can't even imagine. `mysql_*` are old, almost deprecated set of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing your loop, where you loop through your results:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

What you currently did is get the first row from the result.

Comment: It kinda works. But when i type the whole name, like, Led Zeppelin, it returns nothing.